# MediaPlay in Android MusicServices crashes when calling <MediaPlayer>.pause()

Tags: android, service, android-intent, media-player

In our app we have a MusicService. Currently, it works perfectly fine in terms of playing music and stopping it, but that is from starting and stopping the service. We are calling it in other methods, but `mp.pause()` is crashing unless it is surrounded by a null checker. But when it checks for nulls it doesn't work at all. We had all this working earlier, but we started reformatting the way were doing it, because on `Android 4.0 (ICS)` the Music kept playing randomly even when we stopped it, but thats not the point anyway.

```
public class MusicService extends Service {
    public static MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.title_music);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.setVolume(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        mp.start();
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(final Intent intent, final int startId) {

    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(final Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public static void onStop() {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }

    public static void onPause() {
        if (mp!=null) {
            mp.pause();
        }
    }

    public static void onResume() {
        if (mp!=null) {
            mp.start();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
          mp.stop();
          mp.release();
          super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }

}
```

We are using this to start the service in another activity:

```
intent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a log I can't really say with 100% certainty this is the issue, but it would appear that the pause method is being called while mp is in an invalid state. I suggest you change your onPause method so that it reads like so.

```
public static void onPause() {
    if (mp!=null) {
        if (mp.isPlaying())
            mp.pause();
    }
}
```

This will check to see if it is actually playing and will work for any state it is in, except an error state. At least according to the documentation.